# Как сделать плавной переход между двумя векторами?

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    if(Vector3.forward == dir)
    {
        dir=Vector3.left;
    }
    else
    {
        dir=Vector3.forward;
    }
}
    float amout = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Translate(amout*dir);
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть множество уже реализованных вариантов решения:

- [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) - линейная интерполяция векторов
- [Vector3.Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html) - сферическая интерпоояция векторов
- [Vector3.SmoothDamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html) - плавный переход по указанному времени и скорости